# Remove unknow space in .content > div

Tags: html, css, space

[image]Unknown spacing coming again and again in `.content > div`, sometimes at the top and sometimes at the bottom. I tried many ways but nothing worked for me.

How can I remove the unknown spacing from `div`?

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 2px 30px 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content>div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.content>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: white;
}

.content>div>*:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.content>div>div:nth-child(3) {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #87ceeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>H1 heading</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[![enter image description here]

Comment: Well, you always have space at the bottom with `margin-bottom: 5px;` …

Comment: I see spacing in both areas I've marked. Which spacing are you talking about? https://i.imgur.com/XibA9wQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I don't really know what you're after.

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 2px 30px 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* 
.content>div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
*/

.content>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  color: white;
}

.content>div>*:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.content>div>div:nth-child(3) {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #87ceeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i attached a picture, now you can understand

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content>div>*:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  /* remove below Line from your code */
  /* padding: 5px; */
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have two empty divs below each paragraph div. that's what's creating the white space remove them if you don't need them.

```
<div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div></div> <--This is causing your empty space
    <div></div> <--This is causing your empty space
  </div>
```

Comment: i actually need them

Comment: Well the empty space won't go away then. I guess you have two options, either set the background colour of the empty divs to grey as well so they look like they disappeared or set them to ' display: none; ' but that will remove them using CSS so idk.. but those are pretty much your options.